# How to reference a particular item in a nested array in a polymer 1.x dom-repeat template?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a template that goes something like:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{vimeoData}}" as="vim">  
    <img src$="{{vim.pictures.sizes[0].link}}"/>  
    ...  
</template>
```

This of course doesn't show up at all.

Is there a way of just showing the nested array item without having to embed another dom-repeat template and create a filter? Seems like way more effort than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the most straight-forward solution is to massage the data on ready or in your response handler if you're pulling data through something like an iron-ajax element.

Here's how my response handler works with a response wrapping data pulled from the vimeo api (you could do the same in a 'ready' function):

```
...
_responder:function(dt) {
    var vdata = dt.detail.response.results.body.data;
    var vdlength = vdata.length;
    for(var i=0;i<vdlength;i++) {
        var vim = vdata[i];
        vim.thumbnail_uri = vim.pictures.sizes[0].link;   
    }
    this.vimeoData = vdata;
},
...
```